# how change the output IP of every PROXY to it's own IP in CentOS (SQUID- Multiple IP)?

Tags: centos, proxy, ip, squid

i configured a proxy server in **CentOS** server using with **squid**
i have multiple ips like these :

```
192.233.76.1 ~ 100
```

i've added those ips to my **one** interface.
so every **HTTPS** proxy works well -> ip : 443 : username : password
my problem is when i test `192.233.76.2 ~ 100` using with proxifire software the output ip is always `192.233.76.1`.
i am using this site for checking output ip :  http://whatismyipaddress.com/
how can i fix that problem?
i have my own vds and i have all accesses to it.(using with vmware)

Comment: Generally when you use a proxy like squid, it inserts its own address in the outgoing requests, in that way the request is routed back to it, not the originating machine. What you're looking for is called transparent proxying.. and it isn't difficult to do with squid, as 30 seconds with google will show.

Comment: would you plaese help me more, i've googled many times about that. one of my friends told me you should change ded. there other one told me you should write an acl for it. i am a little bit confused about that.

Comment: Well by itself it's a pretty tall order, I really have no idea what sort of infrastructure you have. I suggested reading up on the concept, so you can then come back and ask about the bits you truly don't understand, or which aren't working like you think they should be.

Comment: BTW, an ACL is an access control list, basically it gives you the ability to group people/things together, for example IP addresses. You could group all of your LAN addresses together, then apply rules to the group name, instead of singly for every IP address.

Comment: would you please give me those commands for squid step by step

Comment: Like I said, I have no idea what your infrastructure is like, I couldn't begin to tell you how to configure a proxy for a situation like that. Start reading here: https://workaround.org/squid-acls then here: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl

Comment: What about this:http://www.tastyplacement.com/squid-proxy-multiple-outgoing-ip-addresses ? This is the first result for: "squid multiple interfaces"